# TypeError when using .get_notifications() with pyimgur Python

Tags: python, imgur

I am trying to get notifications using this:

```
pyimgur.User.get_notifications()
```

But it keeps giving me the error:

```
TypeError: unbound method get_notifications() must be called with User instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Here is the link to the pyimgur api [http://pyimgur.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#pyimgur.**init**.User.get_notifications](http://pyimgur.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#pyimgur.__init__.User.get_notifications)
I've already done the authorization. What I really need is a way to know when someone mentions this user in a comment, and using notification is much easier than looking through every comment.

Comment: Shouldn't you be creating an *instance* of the class, i.e. `pyimgur.User().get_notifications()` (note parentheses)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think you're right, but what should I put inside the parentheses? In the site it says (json_dict, imgur, has_fetched=True), I know what `has_fetched` is but I have no clue what to put in `json_dict` and `imgur`

Comment: I don't know, I've never used it. You could look at the code, for example the first `__init__` only cares about `json_dict['url']` - https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur/blob/master/pyimgur/__init__.py#L1238

Comment: @jonrsharpe I take a close look and try everything. I've already spent all night and day working on this, whats a few hours more?